# Concat 2 mongodb collections

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to combine 2 collections into one (not join). I have 2 databases with same collections and collection structure.

As example:

```
Collection test1 db1:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("574c339b3644a65b36e77359"),
    "appName" : "App1",
    "customerId" : "Client1",
    "environment" : "PROD",
    "methods" : []
}

Collection test2 db2:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("574c367d627b45ef0abc00e5"),
    "appName" : "App2",
    "customerId" : "Client2",
    "environment" : "PROD",
    "methods" : []
}
```

I'm trying to create the following:

One collection test db, where the documents will be merged from test1 and test2 but not one with each other. What would be the proper way to achieve this?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("574c339b3644a65b36e77359"),
    "appName" : "App1",
    "customerId" : "Client1",
    "environment" : "PROD",
    "methods" : []
},    
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("574c367d627b45ef0abc00e5"),
    "appName" : "App2",
    "customerId" : "Client2",
    "environment" : "PROD",
    "methods" : []
}
```

The complexity is that ID are referenced in other collection of mongo.

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept it see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

the fastest way will be to create a dump (using mongodump) and restore them at once (example is using windows paths).

```
mongodump  --db test1 --collection test1  --out c:\dump\test1
mongodump  --db test2 --collection test2  --out c:\dump\test2

mongorestore  --db test3 --collection test3   c:\dump\test1
mongorestore  --db test3 --collection test3   c:\dump\test2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @profesor79, would this approach address the part of the "The complexity is that ID are referenced in other collection of mongo."?

Comment: so we have duplicates in source document - is that right?

Comment: I have the id referenced in other collection of the source database, so when the import is done the original id will change and the other collection will still reference to the original id. I can't see any way to solve it except importing one by one in the dependency order and update the original reference to the newly generated _id. Any suggestion how to make it without writing big chunk of code are welcome.

Comment: but _id will be preserved - unless we have duplicates